# Arabic calligraphy - understanding markings

Tags: arabic

A friend of mine is trying to make an atheist t-shirt with just the beginning of the shahada.  Does this look like it has been cut correctly?

What are the commas and upside commas on this piece of calligraphy? I understand the fathah vowel marking and the hamza and the shadda, but there are additional comma-looking markings that I don't understand.   There is also something that looks like a bird over the ll of illahi which I don't get because presumably the thing below it is the shadda.[image: la illahi]

Comment: I don't think language-specific questions about spelling and usage are on-topic here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commas are just decoration to fill the vacant space. Your atheist statement is very clearly written.